# composer content-mismatch length after update to latest 1.4.1

Tags: laravel, composer-php

My `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "alsofronie/eloquent-uuid": "^1.0",
    "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^4.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.5",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.4",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.1",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "graham-campbell/binput": "^3.6",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
    "laravelista/ekko": "^1.3",
    "pda/pheanstalk": "^3.1",
    "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^2.8",
    "spatie/laravel-collection-macros": "^2.0",
    "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^3.3",
    "stefensuhat/flash": "^2.5",
    "stefensuhat/no-captcha": "^1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^7.3"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  }
}
```

Output of `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
```

When I run this command:

`composer update`

I get the following output:

[image]

And I expected to update my package normally.

ALready tried this solution [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch) but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried updating composer?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? `composer clear-cache`, remove your vendor directory then `composer install`

Comment: yes. Apparently windows defender block the connection I don't know why. I install Eset and now its working properly. seems odd windows update block composer @Ian