# I want serve yii application by php yii serve but show me this errors

Tags: php, yii, yii2, autoload, installation-package

The installation status is available in the picture

[image: Composer giving Content-Length mismatch error]
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\web/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\web\index.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\web/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\web\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\web\index.php on line 7

Comment: Try adding `-vvv` to your composer command and try again. There's a network issue somewhere, and that might help track it down.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Force https for packagist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch), [No answer, but mentions Windows Defender blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993660/composer-content-mismatch-length-after-update-to-latest-1-4-1)

Comment: `autoload` file is created after composer successfully downloads all packages,
in your case composer fails and autoload file was not created, try to reinstall all packages