# composer require [package] results in [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to run `composer require laravel/passport=~1.0` but each time it results in the following errors:

```
composer require laravel/passport=~1.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information

The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Content-Length mismatch


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch) I then tried adding this to the bottom of composer.json

```
"config": {
    "github-protocols": [
      "https"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
```

but still getting the same error.  I am no expert in terminal or composer but this happened all of a sudden and I don't think I did anything different that would cause this issue.  Had no problem previously when installing other packages.

Comment: Any better luck with this command: `composer require laravel/passport:~1.0`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Hmmmm, the command I listed above ran fine on my machine. Did it at least give you the same error, or something new? May be due to a poor internet connection, an issue with a firewall, or an issue with DNS. Did you try any of the fixes listed at the page the error mentions?

You can also try adding `"laravel/password": "~1.0"` to the require section of your `composer.json` file and then running `composer install` on the command line. The `composer require` command is essentially a short-cut for doing that. But if you're having connectivity issues, you'll run into the same issue.

Comment: It was the same error message.  I restarted and tried the steps at https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode again and it allowed me to run the command and install the package now, Thank you!