# composer error: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch

Tags: laravel, composer-php

After installing composer I check it with this command:

```
composer diagnose
```

And all things are OK. When I run this command for latest version of Laravel:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

I get error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-01%24b61fc29958261afed83292382737d143f41e535c0e562e62e6aaf5bf30978746.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Or for this command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel proj
```

I get error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch, received 313522 bytes out of the expected 2060799

I checked [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch) but this didn't resolve my problem. I tried using a VPN but the issue persists.

### What is the problem and how I can resolve it?

solved my problem today (11/19/2017)
without any change in config.
i think that problem is in packagist.org or is in my isp.
thanks

Comment: Try running `sudo composer self-update` and then try again

Comment: try it but not working.
You are already using composer version 1.5.2 (stable channel).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: Check the possible duplicate Mohammad.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and using VPN solved my problem.

Comment: worked for me too, but can not understand the reason.