# Composer showing error while installing Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to download Laravel but composer is showing error and stop the installation process after taking much time. I am quoting the exact error,

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     Content-Length mismatch, received 131768 bytes out of the expected 353797
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [] [] []

How can I fix this error and start working on Laravel!

**UPDATE** - I have made the following changes in config.json file.

```
 {
  "config": {
    "github-protocols": [
      "https"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist.org": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
}
```

But then, it also not working!

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch

Answer (score -1):

your "repositories" key in **composer.json** should be like this:

```html
"repositories" : [
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org"
  },
  {
    "packagist": false
  }
]
```

Comment: This was suggested by a contributor to the composer project on github here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5656. Plus, it worked flawlessly for me when i had same issue.