# How to install Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-5.7, laravel-6

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel="5.8.*" larastart
```

it's not working and I tried some other ways too but not worked for me

This is the error I am getting:

> Content-Length mismatch, received 188377 bytes out of the expected 620920 repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name DESKTOP-7CV9HTK
System Manufacturer HP
System Model    HP ENVY Laptop 13-ah1xxx
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  5HZ05PA#AKL
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 1992 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Insyde F.12, 11/8/2018
SMBIOS Version  3.0
Embedded Controller Version 69.72
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  HP
BaseBoard Product   850B
BaseBoard Version   69.72
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   On
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\WINDOWS
System Directory    C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.18362.387"
User Name   DESKTOP-7CV9HTK\Hanifullah Jamalzai
Time Zone   Afghanistan Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   15.8 GB
Available Physical Memory   9.89 GB
Total Virtual Memory    18.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory    10.3 GB
Page File Space 2.38 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions    Yes
Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions   Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware    Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes
```

Comment: Use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel larastart` and check which version is installed ?

Comment: Showing this Error and Not installed any of the versions of laravel:  Content-Length mismatch, received 188377 bytes out of the expected 620920
http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Comment: First, check the version of PHP that should be PHP>=7.1.3. Then run these commands: First, composer global require laravel/installer and second, composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel larastart "5.8.*". Here is laravel installation doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation

Comment: This answer fixed the problem for me. Change you package url to use https. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52002960/909973

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer Content-Length Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch)

Comment: @RishiRaut , after your command, Now I have v6

Comment: @MubasharIqbal Dear Brother Yes the Version of PHP is Higher

Comment: @bassxzero No, Mine is  Different Question

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38635257/4650866 i'm 100% sure it will be resolved

Comment: @Vipertecpro Not solved

Comment: Can you please share your system information as well, also please trying removing temp files from system as well

Comment: @Vipertecpro I will update the question, there I will share

Comment: Hey, have you tried cleaning cache files as well? I had a similar problem on windows resolved by clearing temp files plus you can also try reinstalling composer as well.

Comment: I reinstalled composer again, but the same Error.anyway My friend downloaded it to me and sent to me I am working with it. working normal.

Answer (score 12):

you can try this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName "5.8.*"
```

it requires a double quotes over Laravel version (e.g. 5.8.*) for most systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have composer installed you can simply use following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <your_project_name> "5.8.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel doc is very helpful.you can find all version install code [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation) by changing the version of laravel doc

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourProjectName "5.8.*"
```

above code for creating laravel 5.8 version project.
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command 100% working

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel YOURPROJECTNAME "5.8.*"
```